# Can I arbitrarily pick which resistors I should calculate the equivalent resistance with?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

Let's say I have some random complex circuit of resistors. Maybe something like:
[image]

Now I wanna calculate the equivalent resistance of this whole circuit. Can I just randomly pick which resistors I wanna calculate the equivalent resistance with?

For instance, I start with $R_1$ and $R_2$. I calculate their resistance and I get some equivalent resistance $R_{eq_1}$ and then I randomly pick two others and so on.

Comment: How exactly do you propose to calculate an equivalent resistance of arbitrary pairs like R1 and R2, or R1 and R6? Hint: you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should find the equivalent resistance for resistors which are either in series, eg R9 and R10, or in parallel, eg R3 and R4.
R1 and R2 are neither in series (same current through each of them) nor in parallel (same potential difference across each of them).

Comment: How can I know when two resistors have the same voltage across each of them?

Comment: They have common nodes (connections) at each end and the current into one node having split between the two resistors is the same leaving the other node.

Answer (score 1):

You've drawn a circuit that can be resolved into series and parallel elements. [There are some circuits that can't be so resolved, for example 5 resistors in a *bridge* configuration. Such circuits need rather more sophisticated techniques such as star-delta transformations or application of Kirchhoff's laws.]

I'll start you off on series and parallel resolution  for your circuit...

R3 and R4 are a parallel combination. R5 is in series with this combination. So you can work out the equivalent resistance of the 3 right hand resistors. But this equivalent resistance is in parallel with R6 and R7. So you can work out the equivalent resistance of the 5 right hand resistors.

I'll let you carry on from here.

A couple of things that might help... (a) Redraw the circuit with parallel resistors connected to one common point at each end rather than being 'staggered' along transverse wire(s) as you have done for R3 and R4 and for the bottom ends of R6 and R7. (b) Don't spread series combinations around corners, as you've done for R5 and the the R3, R4 combination. Redrawing in this way might make things clearer; you won't need to do it when you've had more practice.

Good luck!

Comment: Agree with you that in exercises, some diagrams are drawn bad on purpose. Parallel and series configurations are enough here.

Answer (score 0):

Make all the parallel and series combinations and then can be calculated by thavenin equivalent resistance

Answer (score 0):

Before you even start, you need to know the purpose of calculating the equivalent resistance (what you want to do with it), which would then determine the nodes between which you need to calculate the equivalent resistance. Refer to the circuit diagram below where I have identified all the nodes (which assumes the interconnecting wires have zero or negligible resistance).

For example, if you want to know the current drawn from the battery then you would want to determine the equivalent resistance between nodes A and B. On the other hand, if you wanted to determine the Thevenin equivalent circuit looking into terminals E and A, you would want to determine the equivalent resistance looking into terminals E and A.

Once you determine what the equivalent resistance is to be used for, you should go through the circuit to combine the resistors that are clearly in parallel and/or series, and replace them with their equivalent resistances, working your way through the circuit.

> For instance, I start with $R_1$ and $R_2$

You cannot start with $R_1$ and $R_2$ since they are neither in series nor in parallel with each other. Node C below connects together not only those two resistors, but. also $R_8$ and $R_9$.

Instead start with the parallel combinations of $R_3$ and $R_4$, or $R_6$ and $R_7$. If you start with combining $R_3$ and $R_4$ in parallel you can then combine that equivalent resistance in series with $R_5$, and so forth, depending on where you want to end up placing the final equivalent resistance.

Hope this helps.

[image]